# The viewer was unable to find the resources required to render the report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am developing J2EE application with crystal report. When deploying in tomcat server working fine but when am deploying in weblogic getting following error. I don't know how to fix. Any advice?

> The viewer was unable to find the resources required to render the
>   report.   Please check the following to resolve the issue.
>
> 1. Verify that `../../crystalreportviewers120/` is accessible to your WebApp and is the correct path to the viewer resources.
> 2. You may customize this location by altering the `crystal_image_uri` and `crystal_image_use_relative` properties in the `web.xml`.
> 3. Validate that the file `crv.js` exists at `../../crystalreportviewers120/js/crviewer/crv.js`.

Comment: What were the results of the two things to check? _Is_ `../../crystalreportviewers120/` accessible? Is it correct? Does `../../crystalreportviewers120/js/crviewer/crv.js` exist?

Comment: actually i don't know how weblogic is deploying.

Answer (score 0):

When using The Report Viewer JSP Wizard to create a JSP to call the report viewer, automatically a folder named cristalreportviewers is created under WebContent, which contains all resources required to publish the rpt file. It is required to declare its location to the web.xml file. The Developer Guide for Report Viewer declares how to setup both crystal_image_uri and crystal_image_use_relative properties: You need to declare the relative path to that folder (and its right name) for the first property, and set the interpretation of the crystal_image_uri to be relative to the web page, application, or server, for the second property. The name of folder changed from a version to another: While message refers to cristalreportviewers120, in CR 2011 it is named whitout the "120" suffix. Put the right name in the crystal_image_uri parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately this question was asked long ago, and indeed it was solved by some way. However, I prefer to reply because it continues being an issue for other people (like myself)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the crystalreportviewers120 directory (found in C:\Program Files\Common
Files\Business Objects\3.0) to a subdirectory of the same name directly
underneath the Project directory (as a peer to WEB-INF). Ensure that all
contents, both files and subdirectories, are copied—there should be about 150
files in all.

Reference:-

Crystal Reports XI for J2EE Startup Guide.pdf